# How to color the rows and headers of a table with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I need to display 3 types of data with different fields in the same table. To do this, I want to have 3 headers with a different color each.

I use bootstrap to make my design and my code is in Javascript with React.

I wrote the following code to do this (I tried to simplify it but it is normally reproducible)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

//props object
type IPropsTable={
    currentDatas: (DataType1 | DataType2 | DataType3 | undefined;
}

const TableRequest: React.FC<IPropsTable> = ({ currentDatas }) => {

    const [existData1, setExistData1] = useState(false);
    const [existData2, setExistData2] = useState(false);
    const [existData3, setExistData3] = useState(false);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (currentDatas) {
            currentDatas.map((currentData) => {
                if (currentData.type === "data1") {
                    setExistData1(true);
                } else if (currentData.type === "data2") {
                    setExistData2(true);
                } else if (currentData.type === "data3") {
                    setExistData3(true);
                }
            })
        }
    },[currentDatas])   

    function renderTableHeaderData1() {
        let header = ['someField1', 'someField2']

        return header.map((key, index) => {
           return <th key={index}  scope="col">{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
        })
    }

    function renderTableHeaderData2() {
        let header = ['someOtherField1', 'someOtherField2']

        return header.map((key, index) => {
           return <th key={index}  scope="col">{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
        })
    }

    function renderTableHeaderData3() {
        let header = ['someOtherOtherField1', 'someOtherOtherField2']

        return header.map((key, index) => {
           return <th key={index}  scope="col">{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
        })
    }

    function renderTableData() {
        if(currentDatas){
            return currentDatas.map((session) => {
                if (session.type === "data1") {
                    return (
                        <tr key={nanoid()} className="warning">
                            <td>{session.someField1}</td>
                            <td>{session.someField2}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                } else if (session.type === "data2") {
                    return (
                        <tr key={nanoid()} className="info">
                            <td>{session.someOtherField1}</td>
                            <td>{session.someOtherField2}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                } else if (session.type === "data3") {
                    return (
                        <tr key={nanoid()} className="success">
                            <td>{session.someOtherOtherField1}</td>
                            <td>{session.someOtherOtherField2}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                }
            })
        } else{return undefined}
    }  

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <table className="table table-sm">
                    <caption>Result Search</caption>
                    <thead>
                        {existData1? 
                            <tr className="thead-warning">{renderTableHeaderData1()}</tr>
                            : <></>
                        }
                        {existData2? 
                            <tr className="thead-info">{renderTableHeaderData2()}</tr>
                            : <></>
                        }
                        {existData3? 
                            <tr className="thead-success">{renderTableHeaderData3()}</tr>
                            : <></>
                        }
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {renderTableData()}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default TableRequest;
```

As you can see in the code above, I assign a **css** class to each of my `<tr>` (`warning` for data1, `info` for data2 and `success` for data3). But when my component is rendered, no color appears and the table is completely white, either for each of the three headers or for the data contained in each row of the table.

[image: The table I get with the current code which is all white (the large rectangles on the image are used to cover sensitive data)]

I tried using the `thead-warning`, `thead-info` and `thead-success` classes for my table header `tr` css classes, they seemed to be more suitable. But same result, no color is displayed.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong and could guide me in the right direction, I really don't understand where my problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with the name of the **className** I was using to color my table. By using **bg-success** instead of **table-success** everything works normally. But I don't understand why the **table-success** class doesn't work as in this example: [example with table-success](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-background-color-of-table-rows-or-individual-cells-in-bootstrap/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `<tr class="success">` or `<tr class="warning">` (depends what color you want).

Example:

```
<tr class="success">
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I am not sure I understand your proposal. If what you are telling me is to change the term `className` in my **html element** to `class`, it is due to**React** which has for norm to write `className`, writing `class` I get an error.